# Remove combo box item c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to remove the **"Administrator"** text in the combo box items list after checking the **"Administrator"** text in the database, if found, then it will simply remove from the drop down list menu.

Right now, even though there is an **"Administrator"** text in the database, the combo box still add the **"Administrator"** text to it is items list.

Is am wrong somewhere?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
public partial class Registration: Form
{

bool _isCheckedEmail = false;

void Registration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearTextBoxes();

            SystemManager.CheckType("Administrator");

            if (SystemManager._isUsed != true)
            {
                this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Administrator");
            }

            this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Member");

            this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

            SystemManager._isCheckedDisplayName = false;
            _isCheckedEmail = false;

            this.button1.Enabled = false;
            this.button4.Enabled = false;
        }
}
```

And here is the ***"SystemManager"*** class:

```
public class SystemManager
{

public static bool _isUsed = false;

public static void CheckType(string _value1)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(SystemManager.connectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Member] WHERE [UserType] = @UserType";

                connection.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add("@UserType", OleDbType.VarChar);
                    command.Parameters["@UserType"].Value = _value1;

                    using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (_count > 0)
                            {
                                _isUsed = true;
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                _isUsed = false;
                            }
                        }

                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }

                connection.Close();
            }

        }
}
```

Here is the database (I am uploading it to the dropbox):

[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/raulmbjhq0i3n7c/Capture.PNG?dl=0)

Thank you.

Comment: `_count` is always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for above question:

```
    void Registration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SystemManager.ClearTextBoxes(this.Controls);

        if (SystemManager.CheckType("Administrator") != true)
        {
            this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Administrator");
        }

        this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Member");

        this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        SystemManager._isCheckedDisplayName = false;
        _isCheckedEmail = false;

        this.button1.Enabled = false;
        this.button4.Enabled = false;
    }

       public static bool CheckType(string _value1)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(SystemManager.connectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Member] WHERE [UserType] = @UserType";

                connection.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add("@UserType", OleDbType.VarChar);
                    command.Parameters["@UserType"].Value = _value1;

                    _count = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

                    connection.Close();
                }

            }

            return _count > 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

## 1

You can refer the result object by `reader[0]`.

```
using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Integer.TryParse(reader[0].ToString(), _count);
        if (_count > 0)
        {
            _isUsed = true;
        }

        else
        {
            _isUsed = false;
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

## 2

Use `OleDbDataReader.HasRows` property to check the type exists or not.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.hasrows(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM [Member] WHERE [UserType] = @UserType";

connection.Open();

using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@UserType", OleDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters["@UserType"].Value = _value1;

    using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                _isUsed = true;
            }

            else
            {
                _isUsed = false;
            }
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not solve the problem sir @Jumpei. I have tried a couple times, I have changed the `UserType` in the database to the `Member`, and when I run the program, the drop down items list does not show the `Administrator` item. My thought is, the `reader.HasRows` check if there is a row `UserType` in the database, not check the text in it

Comment: Hi sir, I already solved the issue with removing the items in the combo box. Thank you very much.

Comment: @UnknownUser I showed 2 answer. Did u solve the issue by my answer or another?

Comment: None of that sir, sorry. I will post my answer to here. Anyway, thank you for spend your time to answering my question. If you please, I already started a new thread, please have a visit and if can, please give it a solution: [Remove combo box items that stored as hashed in the database c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463642/remove-combo-box-items-that-stored-as-hashed-in-the-database-c-sharp)